# React Hooks: useQuery data are gone after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting data from API using useQuery  when I load the page data is returned,
But when I refresh the page data is gone any idea why?

```
 const { isLoading, data } = useQuery("page-data", () => {
    return api.get(`/landing_pages/204`);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Page data", data); // when I refresh the page its undefined

  }, [])
```

Comment: What do you mean by load the page? A hot reload?

Answer (score 3):

The data is `undefined` as long as your query is loading.
Your `useEffect` has an empty dependency array, so it is executed only one single time when the component gets mounted, but not when it is updated.

But `data` will be defined on the consecutive rendering only, thus when the component gets updated.

So to access it inside of the `useEffect`, you have to add the `isLoading` as a dependency and check for the loading to be completed.

```
 useEffect(() => {
         if(!isLoading){
          console.log("Page data", data); // when I refresh the page its undefined
         }
      }, [isLoading])
```